# Python.NET path to PYTHONNET_PYDLL not working for python311.dll (but works for python38.dll)

Tags: python, c#, .net, python.net

I'm trying to set custom path for "PYTHONNET_PYDLL" and it works correctly when target Python is in version 3.8 but not working when Python is in version 3.11

Here is my (working) code:

```
    System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PYTHONHOME", @"D:\Test\CondaTest8");
    System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PYTHONNET_PYDLL", @"D:\Test\CondaTest8\python38.dll");
    PythonEngine.Initialize();
    using (Py.GIL())
    {
        dynamic np = Py.Import("numpy");
        Console.WriteLine(np.cos(np.pi * 2));
    }
    PythonEngine.Shutdown();
```

And not working one:

```
    System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PYTHONHOME", @"D:\Test\CondaTest");
    System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PYTHONNET_PYDLL", @"D:\Test\CondaTest\python311.dll");
    PythonEngine.Initialize();
    using (Py.GIL())
    {
        dynamic np = Py.Import("numpy");
        Console.WriteLine(np.cos(np.pi * 2));
    }
    PythonEngine.Shutdown();
```

Ended with error:

> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
> 'Delegates' threw an exception. ---> System.DllNotFoundException:
> Could not load D:\Test\CondaTest\python311.dll. --->
> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The specified module could not
> be found.

I need to have few separated portable Python interpreters created using MiniConda and both of them (3.8 and 3.11) was created in exactly the same way, but for some reason 3.8 works flawlessly and 3.11 not.
Python.NET is in vesion 3.0.3.
Of course paths are correct.
How to use Python 3.11 with Python.NET?

PS. Right now I'm using workaround by CliWrap executing script.py trought python.exe from same Python interpreter mentioned before and it works!

Answer (score 0):

Either path has a mistake, or the python311.dll has a dependency that needs to be added to `PATH` for it to be discoverable. The later can be checked using `dumpbin /dependents <dll>` (`dumpbin` is installed with VC++).

Comment: I'm sure that path is correct (I was checking that few times). Still I'm curious why python 3.8 works without any flaws where 3.11 not, but from command line (and CliWrap) there is no any problems. Maybe my way of setting python path for Python.NET is wrong, there is other/correct method?